# ValueError when opening a file, strange symbols

Tags: python, encoding, valueerror

I try to open a file where each contains data with this format :

```
1 5.4 93.6 1.0
```

I checked the whole file it is correct.

My code is :

```
with open('train2.txt') as file:
    data = np.matrix([[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file])
```

But I get the error :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿1'

I first thought it was because my locals were in Japanese as there were japanese symbols instead of the strange ones. I tried to reencode the file after changing the locals back but the error is still there.

Comment: I copied the line you have, removed the last `.` and I got `data=[[ 1.   5.4 93.6  1. ]]`, check if there are encoding issues in your file, especially with the `.` characters

Comment: It's an error there is no point in my file

Comment: you have `.` in `5.4` for example

Comment: This might be a [*BOM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: I tried replacing every old point by a point but it didn't work

Comment: I tried to reencodre without BOM and it looks like it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this it was not getting me any error

```
import numpy as np
with open('file.txt') as file:
     data = np.matrix([[float(x) for x in line.split(' ')] for line in file])
     print(data)
```